# AWS root user permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have made an explicit deny policy for all users on s3 bucket, so now not able to change the policy.
Can root user delete that policy ?
Root user have always an access to change the policies if anything goes wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The AWS root user has all permissions on the account. Login as that user and reset or delete the incorrect policy.